# How to change the returned result of a Spring Roo function

Tags: spring-roo, aop

I am using Spring Roo for my restFull web services. Working great. Now I want to change the default behaviour on all instances. When a post is done I need the resultant record Id returned. The Roo code is

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> MdrAspectController.createFromJson(@RequestBody String json) {
    MdrAspect mdrAspect = MdrAspect.fromJsonToMdrAspect(json);
    mdrAspectService.saveMdrAspect(mdrAspect);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

I would like to change the return to

```
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(mdrAspect, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

meaning it gives back the created record (as I need the record id).

I would like to write an aspect to do this for all Roo_Controller_Json.aj. But it is already an aspect. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to write an aspect change the return value.  I don't think there is any problem having 2 aspects/pointcuts on the same method, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to apply aspects on other aspects. This is even a typical trap that many beginners run into because they forget to exclude their own aspect from its pointcuts, which can lead to advice being called in an endless loop resulting in a stack overflow - nice word to use here. `;-)`

Yes, it is possible to change a method's return value by means of an `around()` advice.

No, it is impossible to access values of local variables from within an aspect. So in your example if you want to access the value of `mdrAspect` you need to get it from another source or create an instance by yourself.

Please tell me if you have more concrete questions.

Comment: So you are saying I cant do what I want - which is to return mdrAspect. mdrAspect is a new, local variable, by definition of POST, and the over-ridding aspect does not have access to local variables. But thanks for very informative reply.